# convert jpg to cbz in sorted order?

Tags: bash, zip, jpeg

This converts all the jpgs to cbz file but the images not in the order.

```sh
zip comic.cbz $(ls -v *.jpg)
```

The jpg files are named as comic-0.jpg, comic-1.jpg, etc.

Any fixes?

Comment: Pipe the results of `ls` to an appropriate invocation of `sort`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filename expansion expands files in order:

```
zip comic.cbz *.jpg
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: the starting pages are the last.

Comment: @Prashant Baid Are you using a different shell?

Comment: Nevermind I didn't realize that you wanted a different sorting method.

Comment: Does `ls -1v *.jpg` produce an output in the order you expect?

Comment: this worked thanks